# why is an element of a ONS under a linear map an element of another ONS

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Suppose I have a Hilbert space $H$ and two orthonormal sets ${e_i}$ and ${f_j}$ and a given linear map from $H$ to $H$. Why is it true that

$$\sum_i \|Ae_i\|^2 = \sum_{i,j}|\langle Ae_i, f_j\rangle|^2$$

Clearly $$\sum_i \|Ae_i\|^2 = \sum_{i}\langle Ae_i, Ae_i\rangle$$. Then lets denote $v_i = Ae_i$. Since ${f_j}$ is a ONS we can write it as

$$v_i = \sum_{j}\alpha_jf_j$$
Thus,
$$\sum_{i}\langle Ae_i, Ae_i\rangle=\sum_{i,j}\alpha_j\langle Ae_i, f_j\rangle$$

which I dont see to how to be equal $$\sum_{i,j}|\langle Ae_i, f_j\rangle|^2$$

Comment: You cannot write $v_i = \sum_{j}\alpha_jf_j$ if $(f_j)$ is just an orthonormal set. It has to be a complete  orthonormal set (a.k.a. orthonormal set basis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your orthonormal sets are complete we have

$\sum_{i,j}|\langle Ae_i, f_j\rangle|^2=\sum_i \sum_j|\langle Ae_i, f_j\rangle|^2=\sum_i\|Ae_i\|^{2}$ since $\sum_j|\langle x, f_j\rangle|^2=\|x\|^{2}$ for any $x$.

Comment: thanks for your answer! The part that is not clear to me is why is $\sum_j |\langle x, f_j\rangle |^2 =\|x\|^2$?

Comment: That is a basic property of an orthonormal basis. See Theorem 4.18 in Rudin's RCA, for example.  @swissy